# Used simplejson.dumps to output to django template, but need to access array using tags

Tags: django, templates

I am returning json from a view to a django template so I can work with the data in javascript, but now I also need one of the arrays to be accessed with django template syntax. This seems to not work so well.

In my view I create a python array with object items. I return simplejson.dumps like this:

```
response_dict = {"Description":pkg.desc,"MyTypes":pkgtypes,...
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='text/javascript')
```

where pkgtypes is the array of objects I am interested in accessing through template tags. I managed to find "|safe" filter which at least shows me that 4 items have been returned to the template, but I cannot access the objects inside. Here is what I've tried:

```
 {% for t in MyTypes|safe %}
    SOMETHING
    <input type="checkbox" name="myTypes" value="{{ t.Val }}" />{{ t.Label }}
 {%  endfor %}
```

the word "SOMETHING" gets written 4 times with checkboxes, but I cannot access "Val" or "Label" which are values that come from the array, like this:

```
[{"Val":myval1, "Label":mylabel1},{"Val":myval2,"Label":mylabel2}...]
```

Should I just build my checkboxes using javascript instead?

Comment: Hang on - where does that template come into it? You return the JSON as an HttpResponse directly from the view, so how is it getting passed to a template? Show your real code.

Comment: Ah, yes. You are so right. I load the template first (code not shown) then I use ajax call to get data (the view I included). I am going to return the checkboxes in my first view that loads the template. Thanks for catching that. Didn't mean to exclude the code, I just wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you applying `safe` to a sequence of items? `safe` works for strings, so if you want to mark stuff as safe, do it before outputting it, like `{{ t.Label|safe }}`

You can also try putting `{% debug %}` somewhere to see what exactly the `MyTypes` variable contains.